# React Native Sentry attachScreenshot permissions

Tags: react-native, sentry, react-native-sentry

I'm using the `attachScreenshot` property in Sentry. Everything works as expected. The only question is, do I have to ask permissions to do this? Similar than camera or bluetooth.

Answer (score 1):

If your app has sensitive data on the screen, you shouldn't enable this feature. Otherwise there's no permission you need to ask from the OS point of view, it should just work.